# Same DataFrame a left joined with DataFrame b and DataFrame c is giving cross join error

Tags: apache-spark

I am joining DataFrame `a` with DataFrame `b` and `c` on id column.

But getting the error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
Detected cartesian product for LEFT OUTER join between logical plans
```

Want to figure out why this error is thrown in this case:

```
a.join(b, b("id") === a("id"), "leftouter").drop(b("id"))
 .join(c, c("id") === a("id"), "leftouter").drop(c("id"))
```

Surprisingly below code works:

```
a.join(b, Seq("id"), "leftouter")
 .join(c, Seq("id"), "leftouter")
```

Is this a bug? Or is it because of the drop during lazy evaluation?

Comment: Please provide sample data for all the dataframes.

Comment: Unfortunately unable to replicate this scenario with sample data, maybe it was something specific to that use case code